# How to catch Amplify-Cognito http calls in Angular 7+

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, xmlhttprequest, amazon-cognito, angular8

In my authorization service I have

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{ CognitoUser} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

...among other methods in the class I have this one to reset password in Cognito

```
export class AuthenticationService {
```

...

```
  passwordResetConfirmation(username, code, new_password){
    Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(username, code, new_password)
    .then(data => {console.log(data)})
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

As you can see there is no HttpClient from Angular here, still Amplify somehow is doing Http requests.
How can I get access to that full response including header. No angular interceptor is catching or doing anything with Cognito. I need to get the status code of the response to make sure it was successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forgotPasswordSubmit promise rejection is the indication of a failure. Check the promise reject in the [.then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). The Amplify Auth [forgotPasswordSubmit](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/auth/src/Auth.ts) function will reject the promise with the err object from the method [CognitoUser.ChangePassword](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/16b669541e55452091db5944fd8c73503312a319/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/README.md).  That simply means additional information such as the http response code can't be received from the [Amazon Cognito Identity SDK](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/16b669541e55452091db5944fd8c73503312a319/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/README.md) framework function response.

If it's absolutely necessary to intercept, consider a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API).  An Amplify Angular app can [create a service worker](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/service-workers) and configure the worker to intercept http network calls.